How to design data consistency check rules
Data Reconciliation Rule Generation
Background:
In the process of e-commerce shopping, when a user places an order, data information will be stored in different systems' tables such as order table, payment table, and settlement table throughout the entire business operation. To ensure the correctness of these data during the circulation process across different systems (e.g., order number, buyer, seller UID, order amount, status, currency, etc.), it is necessary to verify the consistency of these fields in different tables.
For example, in the above scenario, when a user completes a transaction, the following checks should be performed:
order.order_amount == pay.pay_amount;
pay.pay_amount == settlement.pay_amount;
order.seller_uid == pay.seller_uid;
pay.pay_no == settlement.pay_no:

If all the above checks pass, it indicates that the information flow is normal throughout the entire business circulation process. If the checks fail, it is highly likely that there is a problem with the information flow of a certain system, leading to inconsistency in the information.
Prerequisites:
There exist n chains of related tables, with lengths ranging from 2 to m;
The relationships between table fields include ==, !=, >, <, etc., and there may be consistency relationships between a field in table A and a field in table B after simple calculations;
Historical data of inventory tables are available;
Questions:
How to find out which fields are related in the inventory chain and what types of relationships exist;
How to identify the relationships between the fields of a new table and those in the original chain;
And based on the relationships between table fields, generate consistency verification rules.
Want to get some ideas inspired, or find directions for existing solutions.
